# Joining X and Y coordinates from CSV with shapefile

Tags: qgis, shapefile, coordinates, spatial-join

I am working in QGIS. I have a shapefile showing regions of Sweden.

In a CSV-file I have `"X"` and `"Y"` coordinates which I want to link to the shapefile spatially. How can I do it?

Comment: So, you're asking how to [import a delimited text layer](https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/managing_data_source/opening_data.html#importing-a-delimited-text-file) as a feature-layer into QGIS?

Comment: or a spatial join?

Answer (score 2):

1. Import your CSV into QGIS via `Layer > Add Layer > Add Delimited Text Layer...`. Here an additional step with a reprojection of a CSV might be required if your points and a shapefile are in different CRSs.
2. Spatial join of points to polygons or vice versa via `Vector > Data Management Tools > Join Attributes by Location...`

P.S. There are plenty of tutorials available on this topic, just search them online.